# A problem about nonlinear Volterra integral equation

Tags: calculus, integration, integral-equations

Let $u(x)$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$ and satisfies
$$
u(x)=1+\lambda\int_x^1 u(y)u(y-x)dy
$$
prove that $\lambda\leq 1/2$.

My try: My idea is to use Laplace transform. If the 2nd term of RHS is a kind of convolution, then we have
$$
\hat{u}(w)=1/w+\lambda\hat{u}^2(w)
$$
Then we consider this equation as a quadratic equation w.r.t $\hat{u}(w)$. So the discriminant gives $\lambda\leq 1/4$. However, this is not the answer we want and 2nd term of RHS is actually not a convolution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can multiply one of the $u$s with a Heaviside step function. Or differentiate both sides wrt x to get a non linear differential equation instead of an integral equation?

Comment: @mathreadler I have tried differential but it cannot cancel the integral since there is $x$ inside the integral.

Comment: what is $u(y-x)$?